# Custom theme for a dark actionbar / tab bar

Tags: android

I am trying to set a custom actionbar for my app like so

```
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
     <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
     <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyActionWidgetTheme</item>
     <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/BasicActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="BasicActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

when i don't include

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/BasicActionBar</item>
```

The actionbar and tab bar appear dark but i want to set the actionbar's color and keep the tabs dark. When i set the style the action bar changes color but the tabs turn to white.

I am pretty sure the problem is

```
parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar"
```

I have tried any bunch of different possible values for this but can't find one that keeps the tab bar dark

Answer (score 2):

this link helped me http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

```
@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse
```

did the trick